# How can I convert a .mov into a .gif (or a .apng)?

Tags: applications, video, file-conversion

I want to put a .mov file I have as the background for a website. I am guessing the best way to do this would be to convert it to a .gif file but I can't find any programs that do it.

I have tried Handbrake, Graphic Converter and Gif Builder.

Comment: A .mov file is a movie, do you want to have a movie as the background or just a specific frame/picture from the movie?

Comment: I want the movie, like an animated background. It's not a particularly active clip, it's just a face going in and out of focus with a lot of white space around it which I'm planning to put the site's content in.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dergachev/4627207

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gif Ninja](http://gifninja.com/) is a great site for converting videos to gifs. I've used it several times and the gif always comes out great.

Comment: Hm, just tried Gif Ninja and the gif outputted is very low resolution, probably less than 120px... 

Is there anyway to do this at a much better quality?

Thanks very much

Comment: @sanja And you're sure that the video you have is good resolution (just making sure)? I will continue to look around.

Comment: Yeap. I'm not sure how to check exact resolution but I'd say it's HD. It certainly looks like it is when it's fullscreen.

Comment: Do Command-I. Somewhere in the info box should be the dimensions. What format is it in?

Comment: 960X450 It's a .mov file.

Comment: Generally speaking, an animated GIF file is *much larger* than a MOV file with the same quality.

Comment: gifninja.com seems dead :(

Answer (score 22):

For **Terminal** lover

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -s 600x400 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -f gif - | gifsicle --optimize=3 --delay=3 > out.gif
```

- `-r 10` tells ffmpeg to reduce the frame rate from 25 fps to 10
- `-s 600x400` tells ffmpeg the max-width and max-height
- `--delay=3` tells gifsicle to delay 30ms between each gif
- `--optimize=3` requests that gifsicle use the slowest/most file-size optimization

You need to install

- **ffmpeg** to process the video file
- **gifsicle** to create and optimize the an animated gif

---

```
brew install ffmpeg 

#if cask is not installed
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask

#dependency for gifsicle, only required for mountain-lion and above
brew cask install xquartz

brew install gifsicle
```

Above instructions taken from [gist: **dergachev/GIF-Screencast-OSX.md**](https://gist.github.com/dergachev/4627207)

The following error occurred while installing the `ffmpeg`

> Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
>   The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
>   Could not symlink include/libyasm
>   /usr/local/include is not writable.

For this follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14539521/468724)

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/include
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

**Transparency**

The code above don't keep transparent layers. In order to do that, use:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -f gif -lavfi split[v],palettegen,[v]paletteuse out.gif
```

Comment: If you get the `brew link` error, you should also `brew link --overwrite ffmpeg` after `chown`ing to fix permissions on `/usr/local`.

Comment: This is a very handy answer, but I found that gifsicle created pretty horribly compressed frames; the output of movie (game screencap) looked like crap.  There are other options here, including using ImageMagick instead of gifsicle: https://gist.github.com/dergachev/4627207

Comment: Yes I too run this but the output was not upto the marks, resolution was not good.

Answer (score 8):

I've used [www.online-convert.com](http://www.online-convert.com/) to convert Keynote-exported .mov files in to animated gifs. Quick and simple. And the results were good.

You can see the resulting GIF in the answer I gave to this question: [How to partially uncover bullet points in Keynote](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46525/how-to-partially-uncover-bullet-points-in-keynote/46559#46559)

Comment: Works like a charm, free and they don't collect your email address

Answer (score 2):

[image: Gifski screenshot]

[Gifski](https://github.com/sindresorhus/Gifski) makes it very easy to convert a video to an animated GIF. You just drag and drop a video, optionally trim it, choose dimensions, frame rate, and quality, click "Convert", and then done.

Gifski is free, no watermark, and open source.

The benefit of an app over a web service is that the video stays on your computer.

*Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors.*

Answer (score 1):

I've used "jiffy cat" with great results. 
http://gfycat.com/

Comment: gfycat doesn't actually convert the file to GIF anymore -- at least I couldn't find a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Offline solution:

[http://www.gifrocket.com](http://www.gifrocket.com/) is an app for just that! Pretty simple app.

Comment: couldn't manage to get it working :( (no output file generated )

Answer (score 0):

Gifify is a node-based converter which uses ffmpeg and imagemagick under the hood.

Installing on Mac:

```
brew rm --force --ignore-dependencies ffmpeg
brew rm --force --ignore-dependencies imagemagick
brew install ffmpeg --with-libass --with-fontconfig
brew install imagemagick --with-fontconfig
brew install giflossy

npm install -g gifify
```

Now you can convert a video file with:

```
gifify clip.mp4 -o clip.gif
```

You can also set a start and end position in the video and add a text caption:

```
gifify clip.mp4 -o clip.gif --from 01:48:23.200 --to 01:48:25.300 --text 'nip!'
```

> **❗️** *It can take several minutes for the conversion to complete even with smaller videos.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about there conversions but I just converted a short .mov file to an animated gif and if was simple and quick. I used the free app **Adapter** to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I was impressed by https://convertio.co/

I uploaded a `.mov`, waited a few minutes, and downloaded a `.gif`. No fee, no fuss, no watermarks.