# Is there a Mac screen capture tool that will export to animated gif?

Tags: software-recommendation, screen-capture

I'm looking for a screen capture tool working on MacOSX that will export the capture to animated gif.

Comment: Sweet animation - amazing use case. I look forward to ideas how to use the native capture and then post process this...

Comment: Native solution (see [@Saharsh's answer below](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/429743/263317)): "_Record screen using [the built-in Screen Recorder of Mac OS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208721)_" (i.e., CMD + SHIFT + 5 and QuickTime)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

LICEcap is free (GPL), works on MacOSX, and capture animated GIF directly.

http://www.cockos.com/licecap/

It's never too late ;-)

Comment: Reconsidered and gave it a trial run...this is perfect! Works great on my Mac but now would like to see it on RedHat ;-) It's always something.

Comment: While this is my GOTO tool for GIF capture, it is currently not supported on Mac OS 11 (Big Sur) https://github.com/justinfrankel/licecap/issues/92

Comment: Signed up for ask different just to upvote this answer - it's so good

Comment: @Phil as of version 1.31 big sur / M1 is supported

Comment: I like their concept around the frame rate, with the exact number as you are recording the screen. Remember to enable it under your Mac Privacy settings.

Comment: I couldn't make it work with my Dell D6000 Docking station (multiple monitor using DisplayLink). All I see is black screen in the captured GIFs.

Comment: It works on Big Sur now

Comment: And you can install it with brew:

brew install licecap

Comment: It was great before but now the transparent does not allow to interact, it always cover screen.

Answer (score 50):

Starting with **macOS Mojave**, and later, simply press **⇧⌘5** (Shift-Command-5) and you can choose from the following:

- Capture Entire Screen
- Capture Selected Window
- Capture Selected Portion
- Record Entire Screen
- Record Selected Portion

Afterwards, if you want to convert the **MOV** *file* into a **GIF**, you can use [**Gifski**](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/gifski/id1351639930?mt=12) (free at the time of this update) or [**GIF Brewery 3**](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/gif-brewery-3-by-gfycat/id1081413713?mt=12), which is 4.99 (sorry, it used to be free) on the **Mac App Store**.

Note that **GIF Brewery 3** can do screen recording directly to create animated **GIF** *files*.

**Gifski** can also be installed via **Homebrew**: `https://github.com/ImageOptim/gifski`

Comment: This is useful, and a much-needed update. I use [*MacPorts*](https://www.macports.org/) instead of homebrew. Unfortunately [`gifski`](https://github.com/ImageOptim/gifski) isn't available as a MacPort app, but [`gifsicle`](https://github.com/kohler/gifsicle) is.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24526/how-can-i-convert-a-mov-into-a-gif-or-a-apng for options.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351578/can-i-use-preview-to-make-this-gif-file-size-smaller was useful for reducing the size of the resulting GIF in Preview.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks bud 

Comment: Gifksi is an excellent recommendation. I can't believe I hadn't used the native screen capture before. Some great gems here, thank you.

Answer (score 11):

**Using built-in Screen Recording and Shortcuts app from macOS 12+**

**Step 1**: Record screen using [the built-in Screen Recorder of Mac OS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208721): <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>

**Step 2**:  Using the Shortcuts app which comes with Mac OS Monterey(12.0.1). Use the [Video to GIF convertor Shortcut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5P2qHT_uwuM) to get the intended GIF file.

Answer (score 10):

### Semi-automated process:

If you need to capture video and convert it to GIF, or a very long involved sequence of steps, then you'll need to combine two separate programs.  A video screen capture tool, and a movie to gif conversion tool.

Look at these two questions for possible solutions:

[Screen video capture application](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4495/screen-video-capture-application)

[How can I convert a .mov into a .gif (or a .apng)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24526/how-can-i-convert-a-mov-into-a-gif-or-a-apng)

There don't seem to be that many apps that do the movie --> gif conversion on OS X, though.  A lot of people use VLC to capture frames and imagemagick to collect them back together into an animated gif.  This is probably why the only answer to the conversion question above used an online service.

### Manual process:

There is a way to do it in OS X without an additional tool, and this works well if, for instance, you just want to show someone the sequence of steps to disable a particular system preference.  The basic process is this:

1. Use Cmd-shift-4-spacebar to capture a screenshot of the window for each frame.
2. Convert the images to gif (or set your screenshot preferences to gif prior to capturing the screenshots)
3. Open the last screenshot in preview.
4. Open the sidebar in preview
5. Show the screenshots in finder, ordered by date
6. Select the remainder to the screenshots, drag and drop them directly on top of the icon in the sidebar of preview for the file already opened.  If you drop them elsewhere it won't add them properly.
7. Preview the animation by selecting the top icon in the sidebar, then using the down arrow.  Rearrange any that are out of order using the sidebar to drag and drop.
8. Save the document as gif, and then preview using a browser, or another app that shows animated gifs.

This technique is somewhat limited in that you can't easily capture video frames without pausing the video before each capture (for that you should get a video screencapture program and then convert the resulting mov or avi to animated gif), and you can't readily adjust the frame time for each frame.

There's a more detailed tutorial with example here:

http://ipliance.com/index.php/eng/Blog/Howto-Animated-GIF-s-Creation-and-Display-in-OS-X

Comment: Yeah I saw this process mentioned quite a few times across my search results. I don't like it as it would be much too tedious. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Impossibly tedious for anything other than a super simple animation. The "typing text in a TextEdit" window example that accompanies this approach on all the web pages that talk about it is about as complicated as you'd want to get with this.

Comment: Ok @Adam, thank you for expanding on your answer. The semi-automated seems to be a lot better than the manual process, however, I'm still surprised it's not already in existence as a feature in some of the larger screen capture tools.

Comment: @KyleHayes Camtasia for PC captures and can export as an animated gif, but Camtasia for Mac doesn't export to gif (yet?).  It's probably worthwhile calling them and finding out if they have plans to release that feature in the future.

Comment: Tutorial link is dead.

Answer (score 7):

I am using a utility called Claquette. It can be used to convert video files to GIFs and it also comes with an integrated screen recorder.
The app is a free [download on the Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/at/app/claquette-gif-video-tool/id587748131?l=en&mt=12).
It's editing capabilities are very limited (just [crop & trim](https://www.peakstep.com/claquette/)), but usually that's enough for me.

To compare the results, I replicated the GIF in your question. My version came up as a ~35s long animation with a file size of 511KB:
[image: brew]

There are plenty of other tools out there - I went with this one because it provided the best quality/size trade-offs in the exported GIFs (which I usually attach to a newsletter service with size limitations).

Answer (score 6):

I just used [www.convert-image.com](http://www.online-convert.com/) to convert a Keynote-export QuickTime movie file in to an animated GIF and it worked great. The process was relatively painless and the end results was a animation I used to answer a question here on AskDifferent: [How to partially uncover bullet points in Keynote](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46525/how-to-partially-uncover-bullet-points-in-keynote/46559#46559)

[image: The End Result]

Comment: I just used that site to convert a ScreenFlow capture to an animated .gif for my IT how-to wiki, worked great - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is a really fantastic guide at http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/11/21/creating-animated-gif-screen-captures-on-osx/

In summary

1. Record video using QuickTime Player
2. Converting the screen capture video to animated GIF (with GIF Brewery)
3. Crop and shrink the capture area
4. Use low FPS

Answer (score 1):

[Cleanshot X](https://cleanshot.com/) has support for this feature (Available through SetApp, otherwise you can buy the base tier for $29, or subscribe for $8 a month). While it's pricey for what essentially amounts to "screenshots/recordings but better", it includes a quick image editor, ability to upload to their cloud storage, and all sorts of other features.

Answer (score 1):

Was also looking for a good, no-data-shared, screen recorder which could record and convert that recording into gif.

**This is the only website you'll need: [gifcap.dev](https://gifcap.dev/)**

It's not only free, client-side and runs in-browser only, but it's also open-source, check it out: [github.com/joaomoreno/gifcap](https://github.com/joaomoreno/gifcap)

Answer (score 1):

Kap works well for me, so maybe for others too.

https://getkap.co/

Answer (score 0):

I use an app called GIPHY CAPTURE, which is free on the Mac App Store.

https://giphy.com/apps/giphycapture

It lets you size an area of the screen, specify animation rate, and then saves the file when you're happy with what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Filmage Screen](https://www.filmagepro.com/filmagescreen). It can export as GIF