# Can I use Preview to make this GIF file size smaller?

Tags: preview, graphics, image-editing

Here is a 2.6 MB GIF that I would like to post in a Stack Exchange question. That means it needs to be under 2 MB or 2 MiB (I can't remember which).

https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/spaceharpoon.gif

Viewing the GIF frame-by-frame with Preview, I can see that there are

1. Some doubled frames that could be removed
2. Some frames at the end that could be removed

In addition I might want to

3. resize all frames by say 20%
4. slow down the replay speed to compensate for the removed doubled-frames

Can I do any (or even all) of these using Preview (or anything else available standard in MacOS) and then save as a repeating GIF?

---

**Update:** I was successful in deleting enough frames using Preview, and to successfully [include the edited GIF in an SE question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26193/12102) with some difficulty (Preview freezes and "jiggling thumbnail" warnings. However that converts it to a non-repeating GIF.

**GIF is now non-repeating, reload to replay**, or watch the video: https://youtu.be/3oryJMdonUA

[image]

Comment: I don't know any default OSX apps, that could edit GIF like you described above. I haven't tried it so I don't know if it's possible, but you could try using the automator and edit frame by frame systematically. But slowing the replay speed... I suggest using the online browser GIF editor.

Comment: @VictorFran I totally forgot about Automator, thanks! I'll have a look to see what's possible. I'm more of a python than an online person, so if I can't find a way to do this with MacOS I'll do it by scripting.

Comment: @VictorFran I've had partial success, see edit.

Comment: Here ya go.   https://i.imgur.com/2zFDlC0.gif . Resized for you. 1.8 mb

Comment: @wch1zpink sweet!, thank you very much! I've now reposted it [there](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26193/12102)

Comment: This is what I used.   https://gfycat.com/gifbrewery

Comment: @wch1zpink that's quite handy, tnx!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can. Open the gif in Preview and you'll get (I got) 48 images. Click on the "View" menu and select "Thumbnails" to display all images as Thumbnails. Give it a second or 2 to display all images. Once that is done go to "Edit" menu and select "display all" or click ⌘-a (command-a) to select all the thumbnails. Next go to "Tools" in the menu bar and select "Adjust Size".  This brings up a pane where you can adjust the image size using standard sizes or by the number of pixels. It will use your settings on all selected thumbnails.

Comment: I have been able to delete frames and save, I'll try this next, *thank you!* However, when I saved, the GIF no longer played continuously. I've tried resizing as you describe, and I get the single-play results as well. Do you know if there's any way to avoid this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWMOA.gif

Comment: Interestingly Preview makes the file size larger (I scaled them down 50% and got a gif with more than 10x file size of the original)

Comment: to make it play continuously after resizing in preview, I used this online utility: https://onlinegiftools.com/change-gif-loop-count

Comment: Amazing answer! Had no idea this could work. Ended up getting a ~100MB animated GIF down to 1.5MB with hardly any visual loss. Great to know this is possible simply inside Preview with no 3rd party or online software.