# Reveal each bullet by opacity in Keynote 6.6?

Tags: keynote, animation

This question is an exact duplicate of [How to partially uncover bullet points in Keynote](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/46525/17907) except that I am asking for the current generation of Keynote ([version 6.6.1, rather than Keynote '09](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keynote_(presentation_software)#Version_history)).

I want the slide to initially appear with all bullet groups translucent (dimmed by opacity set to low number). On each click fully reveal each bullet group by becoming opaque (opacity set to 100%).

As seen in this animated gif:

[image: animated gif image with each of four bullet items appearing from translucent to fully opaque]

I want the same effect as `Build In` > `Appear & Move` > `Dissolve` with `Delivery` set to `By Bullet Group`, but I want the initial display of all bullet groups to be translucent rather than hidden.

My motivation is so that while giving a presentation I can see all the items immediately to remind me how to properly phrase my speaking, yet keep the audience’s attention on each bullet point.

Comment: A comment on the accepted answer of the question you linked says it will work for 6.5, so hopefully it will work for 6.6 as well if you want another option.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I tried and it worked in Keynote 6.6.1 (2560):

- Create Bullet points text.
- Select all bullet points and Copy
- Select all
  but the first bullet point and set color to 10% white (or whatever you like) leaving the first line at 100%.
- Paste the saved bullet points over the existing and align precisely.
- Apply the following setting to the newly pasted bullet points:

[image]

Using the Animate tool and the settings in the Build In automator `Appear`, the first bullet point will present in full 100% luminance with the succeeding points dim. As you click, the bullet points will appear as you have shown in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the work. But that is way too much work to be practical. I want this behavior on all slides.

Comment: Doing so for all slides is not possible just with a single text list.  @IconDaemon solution is easy to duplicate and just adjust the text after the copy paste and or duplicate.  However, if you already have the entire file made, it could become tedious.  You could offer the idea as feedback to Apple. See [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275298/120171) to the question referenced by the OP