# Keynote - gray out previous bullets

Tags: keynote

In Keynote 6.6.1, how do I make the "previous" bullets become grayed-out when advancing bullets?

I know it has something to do with "Build Order" and "build out", but I don't want the bullets to completely disappear (with splashy animations) after they are no longer "current". **Rather I want them to remain visible, but in a slightly diminished form.**

**How to achieve that?**

I used to have this nailed down, but I think the UI has changed and/or I forgot how to do this.

Kinda inverse of the animated gif found in the question here: [Reveal each bullet by opacity in Keynote 6.6?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227805/reveal-each-bullet-by-opacity-in-keynote-6-6)

Comment: Same as http://superuser.com/questions/86185/iwork-09-keynote-is-there-is-straightforward-way-to-dim-and-highlight-each but that one is about a very old Keynote version and is on superuser instead of AskDifferent.

Answer (score 10):

Ok. Found it. You just have to select "By **highlighted** bullet" instead of "By bullet" for build order.

Has nothing to do with build-***out***!

Comment: nice one, +1 from me; i was in exact situation: i (thought) i had this dialed, but UI changed. your solution is essentially a keynote shortcut for a pattern that used to take quite a few manual steps.